# Getting more than the number of friends allowed by Twitter API using rtweet

Tags: r, twitter, rtweet

I have written the following script that fetches friends of Twitter users ("barackobama" in this example) in batches of 75,000 (5000 friends per API call x 15 API calls) every 15 minutes using `rtweet`. However, after the script is done running, I find that the friend ids repeat after a fixed interval. For instance, rows 1, 280001, and 560001 have the same ID. Rows 2, 280002, and 560002 have the same ID, and so on. I'm wondering if I'm understanding `next_cursor` in the API incorrectly.

```
u = "barackobama"
n_friends = lookup_users(u)$friends_count
curr_page = -1
fetched_friends = 0
i = 0
all_friends = NULL

while(fetched_friends < n_friends)  {

  if(rate_limit("get_friends")$remaining == 0) {
    print(paste0("API limit reached. Reseting  at ", rate_limit("get_friends")$reset_at))
    Sys.sleep(as.numeric((rate_limit("get_friends")$reset + 0.1) * 60))
  }

  curr_friends = get_friends(u, n = 5000, retryonratelimit = TRUE, page = curr_page)
  i = i + 1
  all_friends = rbind(all_friends, curr_friends)
  fetched_friends = nrow(all_friends)
  print(paste0(i, ". ", fetched_friends, " out of ", n_friends, " fetched."))
  curr_page = next_cursor(curr_friends)
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. From [the documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-followers-ids):

> this ordering is subject to unannounced change and **eventual consistency issues**

For very large lists, the API simply won't return all the information you want.